# Programmatically sum columns of a data frame?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
dd <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 3), x2 = c(3, 4, 5), x3 = (5, 6, 7))
```

I want to create a new column, like so:

```
dd$x.sum <- dd$x1 + dd$x2 + dd$x3
```

But instead of writing out the addition (suppose I actually have 100 columns `x1, x2, ..., x100` that I want to sum together), I want to write it programmatically. Something like:

```
dd$x.sum <- sum(sapply(1:3, function(i) { 
                              return(dd[paste0("x", i)]) 
                            }))
```

Except that doesn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: does `dd` have other columns with different names? Otherwise this should work - `dd$x.sum <- rowSums(dd)` ?

Comment: Yeah, `dd` has other columns I don't want in the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use `Reduce` with `+`, although this won't have an `na.rm`  argument

```
dd <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1e6),ncol=1000))

dd$sum <-     Reduce('+', dd[paste0('X',seq_len(1000))])


# some benchmarking
xx <- paste0("X", seq_len(1000))
library(microbenchark)
microbenchmark(Reduce('+', dd[xx]), rowSums(dd[xx]))
## Unit: milliseconds
##                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
## Reduce("+", dd[xx]) 14.93642 15.19713 15.56077 15.78606 31.92162   100
##    rowSums(dd[xx]) 30.79629 31.44574 31.67192 32.14342 58.07938   100
```

Comment: Wow, I would not have expected that

Comment: Neither did I @RicardoSaporta, `rowSums` does convert to a matrix internally, perhaps that is what is slowing it down.

Comment: Definitely good to know.  And I wonder how much `+` being primitive also comes into play

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for iteration:

```
dd$sum <- rowSums(dd[paste0("x", 1:3)])
```

However, if you want to iterate you can over the index themselves:

```
dd$sum <-  rowSums(sapply(paste0("x", 1:3), function(ind) dd[[ind]]))
```

---

The reason the `sum(sapply(...))` statement is not working as you have it is because `sapply` is returning a list, and `sum` cannot take a list as an argument

Comment: @mnel, I'm not following.  I dont spot the difference between what you have in the comment and what it's in my answer?

Comment: hmmm, I'm sure that first line wasn't there when I commented. Nevermind.

Comment: @mnel, oh possibly.  I was editing my answer after I posted it.  I thought you were trying to tell me that there were something off in what I put